# User input array in C

Tags: c

Hello I am trying to make a program that lets the user input the size of the array.

I am stuck on making my array sized based on the user. This is what I have so far

```
void main(void)
{
const int size = 0;
int aval[size], i;


printf("Please enter the size of the array: ");
scanf("%i", &size);

printf("\n\nPlease enter array values:\n");
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    scanf("%i", &aval[i]);
}

while (!_kbhit());
}
```

Comment: You have to declare the array *after* the user enters `size`. The array size doesn't change when you update the variable.

Comment: Expanding on Barmar's comment, to fix this, move `int aval[size]` to _after_ the `scanf("%i",&size);` line

Comment: Also (as a deleted answer from @GA1I) you can't enter a value for `const int size` until you remove the `const` qualifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way would be:

```
int size = 0;
int *aval;

printf("Please enter the size of the array: ");
scanf("%i", &size);
/* Should verify size is reasonable here */

aval = malloc(size * sizeof(*aval));
printf("\n\nPlease enter array values:\n");
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    scanf("%i", &aval[i]);
}
```

Doing it this way creates the array in the proper data area, rather than in the local automatic area, which may have limited size.  Also, if you are done with the array before the end of the program, then you can free it to recover the space.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `size` with 0 and then create an array of the size of `size`, which is 0. Later `size` is changed, but that is not entangled to your array. Try this:

```
//Something before
const int size = 0;


printf("Please enter the size of the array: ");
scanf("%i", &size);


int aval[size], i;

//Something after
```